# how many ways to extract day in date column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from TNAME where
  to_char (tran_date,'YYYY') = 2018
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That query is product specific.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL then this function may help you.
SELECT DAY('03-02-2018')

Comment: not much aware about dbms , am using Oracle sql devloer console

Comment: the date function are   stricty related  to db brand so you should tag your question properly

Comment: Oracle DB is here...

Comment: It isn't clear what you are actually trying to do or what problem you are having. What data do you have and what output do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Extract *day*? Your code suggests *year*, so - I'll use a *year* instead. Here are some options to do that:

```
SQL> select count(*) from dual where extract(year from sysdate) = 2018;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select count(*) from dual where to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') = '2018';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select count(*) from dual where trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') = date '2018-01-01';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL>
```